Separate <thead> and <tbody> in Tabularray with Accessibility
I'm working on a LaTeX document using the tabularray package and have added accessibility hooks using the hook and html libraries. However, I can't figure out how to separate the <thead> and <tbody> tags in the output.
MWE:
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-I}}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{hook,html}
\AddToHook{env/tblr/before}{\tagstructbegin{tag=TABLE}\tagmcbegin{tag=TABLE}}%
\AddToHook{env/tblr/after}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}%
\AddToHook{tabularray/row/before}{\tagstructbegin{tag=TR}\tagmcbegin{tag=TR}}%
\AddToHook{tabularray/row/after}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}%
\AddToHook{tabularray/cell/before}{\tagstructbegin{tag=TH}\tagmcbegin{tag=TH}}%
\AddToHook{tabularray/cell/after}{\tagmcend\tagstructend}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{}ll@{}}}
\hline
\SetCell[c=1]{l}{Head A} & \SetCell[c=1]{l}{Head B}\\
\hline
{1} & {1,2,3}\\
{2} & {1,3}\\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}

Current Output:
The entire table is wrapped in <TABLE>. See the screenshot:

Expected Output:
The header rows should be wrapped in <thead>, and the remaining rows in <tbody>. See the expected structure:

I've explored using \AddToHook for finer control over rows but couldn't identify how to insert <thead> and <tbody> tags in the correct positions.
How can I modify the MWE to produce the expected output with separate <thead> and <tbody> tags? Is there a built-in feature in tabularray, or do I need to customize the hooks further?
Edit Note: Updated the question to reflect the correct accessibility structure, ensuring only header cells are marked as <TH> and data cells as <TD>.

you are marking every cell as TH, but this is wrong, only header cells are TH, the other should be TD. Apart from this: tabularray is still missing full support, see e.g. https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/27

Thank you for pointing out the issue with marking all cells as <TH>. I understand that only header cells should be <TH>, while the others should be <TD>. I will correct that in my code.
As for the missing full support in tabularray, I appreciate the reference to the GitHub issue. Given this limitation, is there a workaround or an alternative package that you would recommend achieving the desired output? Specifically, I need the accessibility structure to separate <thead> and <tbody> properly.
